# Subversion + Vimdiff: how to abandon the diff process?

Tags: vim, svn, vimdiff

I have configured svn to open differences using the text (i.e. not graphical) version of vim. Whenever I'm satisfied viewing the changes of the current file I quit vim -- with `:qa` -- and the next file is opened up. How can I abort this process without the need to view all of the files? (I don't know if this is something that must be done within vim or svn.)

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I tried some experiments using Perforce's `p4 diff` command. I first tried Ingo's `:cquit` suggestion, but p4 ignored the return status and continued with the next file. I then executed `:!ps -fH` to find the PID of Vim's parent process, p4, and then executed `:! kill pid`, where `pid` is the PID found from `ps`. That killed p4, but it also left my terminal in an odd state. I had to execute `reset` at the shell prompt to restore it. As I said, not a good solution, but maybe it will stimulate some others' thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how exactly the invocation of Vim from svn works (and you didn't list your configuration so that I could quickly try this), but you could try quitting Vim with `:cquit`, which sends an error code back to the invoking process. Maybe that causes svn to abort the loop.